# Display post by click on the link

Tags: posts, query

I need to display correspond post inside div content(left) when click on a list of links (right), I can not figure out how to pass the post ID & load the php in div (left) when click on the link.

This is my code:

```
  <div class="display-post">
               <?php $args = array(
                          'post__in' => array(111,444,555) /*how to pass list of ID here*/
                );

                $posts = get_posts($args);

                foreach ($posts as $p) :
                //post!
                endforeach; ?>

 </div>


 <div class="lists of link">
    <a href="#">Link a</a> //displays post id: 222 & 333; when click
    <a href="#">Link b</a> //displays post id : 111 & 444 & 555 when click 
 </div>
```

I'm quite new and don't know how to call the click event to pass the value in div class"display-post".

I think im gonna have to use jquery ajax method to do that but its not very clear for beginner like me, hope anyone has experienced can give me easier instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [Query String](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/725678/whats-query-string-in-php).
First you have to make [template](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/) in your theme folder. To show post list on right side and description of post on left side I am using `div` with class name `right` and `left` (specify your desires css properties in those classes).

> To show list of posts in right side div

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Posts
*/
get_header();   
?>
<div class="right" style="float:right;; width:40%;">
<?php

 $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',  //Specyfying post type    
'posts_per_page' => 10,  //No. of posts to show     
'paged' => $paged       //For pagination
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    //To get ID of post
    $id = get_the_ID();
```

The above code is simply creating loop to display lists of posts that happens in every post list or archive page. And to display title of posts we simply use `the_title()` function with permalink.

But in this case to make title as link of post we won't use permalink, instead of permalink we will use custom `anchor tag (<a>)` with query string concept to make title clickable. To achive this we have to specify `if` condition in `url`. In `url` `if` condition is denoted by `question mark (?)`.

```
    //To show Title of post
    ?>      
    <a href="http://localhost:85/sdc/abc/?postid=<?php echo $id; ?>" style="color:#444444;"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <br> <?php
endwhile;
?>
</div>
```

In url of anchor tag of above code we are storing Post's ID in a variable `postid (?postid=)`. `$id` variable contains Post's ID (as we stored post id in this variable using `get_the_ID()` function in above code). And we are assigning value of `$id` to `postid`. So now `postid` contains the Id of post.

> TO show discription of posts on left side on click

Now we have `postid` variable in which ID of post has been stored and we just need to fetch that value/ID from `postid`. To fetch value of `postid` we will use `$_GET['postid']` method as shown below.

```
<div class="left" style="float:left; width:40%;height:auto;">
<?php

    $post = $_GET['postid'];  //Fetching value of postid from url
```

Now we have value of `postid` in variable `$post`. In other words `$post` now contains the ID of post whose description we need to show in left side of page. Now we just need to use that ID to call content of post to the current page. For that following functions will do the trick.

```
    //To show post's content
        $include = get_posts("include=$post");
      $content = apply_filters('the_content',$include[0]->post_content);
      echo $content;

?>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

**Note**: Read all description and also all comments on code lines to understand the code completely. I tried to make it as simple as pasible but still if have any doubt then ask.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much, this is very details and helpful.